# requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"] returns null in JSF

Tags: jsf

As i know of JSF, by default use forward to handle page navigation but why requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"] returns null (does not display in outcome.xhtml page). Here are sample codes:

index.xhtml

```
<h:body>
<h1>Index page</h1>
<h1>Request URI: #{request.requestURI}</h1>
<h1>Forward Request URI: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}</h1>
<h1>Forward Servlet Path: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}</h1>
<h:form>
    RequestScoped input: <h:inputText value="#{requestScopedBean.input}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{requestScopedBean.submit}" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

outcome.xhtml

```
<h:body>
<h1>Outcome page</h1>
<h1>Request URI: #{request.requestURI}</h1>
<h1>Forward Request URI: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}</h1>
<h1>Forward Servlet Path: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}</h1>
<h1>Requestscoped output: <h:outputText value="#{requestScopedBean.input}" /></h1>
```

RequestScopedBean.java

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RequestScopedBean {

private int id;
private String input;

public String getInput() {
    return input;
}

public void setInput(String input) {
    this.input = input;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Random random = new Random();
    id = random.nextInt();
    System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " id: " + id);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String submit() {
    System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " invokes submit() method");
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
    return "outcome";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As i know of JSF, by default use forward to handle page navigation

Judging by the *xhtml* extension you are using Facelets for your *view definition language*.

If you were using JSPs as your VDL then you would be correct as [RequestDispatcher.forward](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) is a standard mechanism used to dispatch a request from a servlet to a JSP.

However, Facelet views are handled entirely by the JSF implementation and there is no need to delegate view rendering to the container. [RequestDispatcher.forward](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) is not required.

Comment: Hi I'm not talking about MVC pattern with servlet + jsp, I just want to know whether method public String submit() use forward or redirect mechanism to navigate to "outcome". If forward is assumed, then why requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"] display nothing in outcome.xhtml

Comment: JSF has a servlet that uses that MVC pattern with JSPs but does not with Facelets. "javax.servlet.forward.request_uri" is not set because forward is not called with Facelets. The _NavigationHandler_ does not call _forward_ with the Facelet VDL.

Comment: You hit exactly to the point!! Where can i find documents and examples pertaining to NavigationHandler, thanks alot.

Comment: You can start with the [JSF 2 specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) but what the _NavigationHandler_ does under the covers depends on the implementation. You will need to look at the source code. You're probably using either [Mojarra](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/) or [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/).